# Orthonormal Basis of Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm confused regarding finding the orthonormal basis of all symmetric functions between $-\pi$ to $\pi$.
So, for symmetric functions, $g(y) = g(-y)$
How do we approach this problem since I have no clue which symmetric functions exactly are we talking about apart from the fact that this is a subspace of vector space $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ and the orthonormal basis of the space is:

$$\{1/\sqrt
{2\pi},\  \cos(nx)/\sqrt{\pi},\  \sin(nx)/\sqrt{\pi}\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the even basis elements of the standard Fourier basis functions in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ form a basis of the even functions. Likewise, the odd basis elements of the standard Fourier basis functions in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ for a basis of the odd functions in $L^2$. Moreover, the odd functions are orthogonal to the even. $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ is decomposed into the orthogonal sum of the even and odd functions. You could write this as
$$
       L^2[-\pi,\pi]=L^2_{e}[-\pi,\pi]\oplus L^2_{o}[-\pi,\pi].
$$
Every $f\in L^2_{e}[-\pi,\pi]$ is an even function and every $g\in L^2_{o}[-\pi,\pi]$ is an odd function. Every $f\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ can be decomposed into
$$
          f=f_{e}+f_{o}
$$
in the usual way where $f_e(-x)=f_e(x)$ and $f_o(-x)=-f_{o}(x)$, which are a.e. identities.